# What's wrong with my grub configuration?

Tags: 11.10, grub2, windows-7, windows-xp

I have one hard drive with 2 partitions. I had Windows XP and Windows Seven installed.
I've deleted Seven partition and installed Ubuntu 11.10 on it.
But when I turn on the computer and the grub menu appears on the screen, I can only see my ubuntu installations and a windows 7 loader. I've already got installed windows XP on another partition, but it doesn't boot.
If I want to use Ubuntu alongside Windows XP, ¿how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info)

Answer (score 0):

Remove Windows 7 hidden partition if You haven't and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I've found:
-73GB NTFS (My XP installation).
-76GB Extended
-70GB ext4
-6 GB swap
-11GB Free